# ASIC design for a specific Fully-connected nn or for a CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network, verilog, hardware

my question is:

for example: i have a trained FCC and i want to implement it on Hardware(ASIC). i want to ask how to utilize weights and biases from trained model in verilog ? 
Should i make RAM and then store the values in it, or is any other way to be used?
I need this values(weights and biases) to propagate them to MAC units.

Comment: There is no answer to your question. The implementation details are up to you. Using ram sounds ok but you should deside what to use and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weights and biases need to be converted into specific number format (say Fixed Point) and then stored in RAM.

Then the values should be fetched and given to the MAC units.